# What is the difference between Files.walk.filter and Files.find?

Tags: java, file, path, nio2

This code searches for a specific file:

```
Stream<Path> findMyFile = Files.find(Paths.get("c:\\temp\\pathtest"), Integer.MAX_VALUE,(p, a) -> p.endsWith("test.txt") && a.isRegularFile());

Stream<Path> findMyFileSecond = Files.walk(Paths.get("c:\\temp\\pathtest"),Integer.MAX_VALUE).filter(p -> p.endsWith("test.txt"));

findMyFile.forEach(System.out::println);
findMyFileSecond.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Both results contain the same files and both methods complete in almost the same time. 
JavaDoc says the following:

> This method walks the file tree in exactly the manner specified by
>        * the  #walk walk method Compare to calling 
>        * java.util.stream.Stream#filter filter on the Stream
>        * returned by {@code walk} method, this meth od may be more efficient by
>        * avoiding redundant retrieval of the  BasicFileAttributes

When should I use `walk` in combination with `filter` and when `find`? What is considered best practice?

Comment: [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) is pretty clear.  `find` is better than `walk` if you’re only planning to apply a filter to the Stream returned by `walk`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: if you you need to filter out files/dirs by attributes - use `Files.find()`, if you don't need to filter by file attributes - use `Files.walk()`.

**Details**

There is a *slight* difference which is actually explained in the documentation, but in a way that it feels completely wrong. Reading the source code makes it clear:

- **Files.find:**

  ```
  return StreamSupport.stream(...)
                          .onClose(iterator::close)
                          .filter(entry -> matcher.test(entry.file(), entry.attributes()))
                          .map(entry -> entry.file());
  ```
- **Files.walk:**

  ```
  return StreamSupport.stream(...)
                          .onClose(iterator::close)
                          .map(entry -> entry.file());
  ```

This means that if, in your eventual filter, you need to get and validate file attributes - chances are that `File.find` will be faster. That's because with `File.walk`, your filter callback will need an extra call to e.g. `Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class)`, while with `File.find` - the attributes are already retrieved and given to you in the filter callback.

I just tested it with my sample 10K-files-in-many-folders structure on Windows, by searching **files only** (i.e. excluding folders):

```
// pre-Java7/8 way via recursive listFiles (8037 files returned): 1521.657 msec.
for (File f : new File(dir).listFiles()) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        _getFiles(files, path, pattern);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

// Files.walk(8037 files returned): 1575.766823 msec.
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    files = stream.filter(p -> {
        if (Files.isDirectory(p)) { return false; } // this extra check makes it much slower than Files.find
        ... 
    }).map(p -> p.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// Files.find(8037 files returned): 27.606675 msec.
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p, a) -> !a.isDirectory())) {
    files = stream.filter(p -> { ... }).map(p -> p.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// Files.walkFileTree(8037 returned): 27.443974 msec.
Files.walkFileTree(new File(path).toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() { 
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path p, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        ...
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

Comment: Excellent, [`BasicFileAttributes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastAccessTime--) have their use-cases, `isRegularFile`, `lastModifiedTime` and such.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `walk()` would be advantageous if you would need to apply some intermediary operation on the directory listing before applying a filter or parallelize the stream.